# Как найти коммиты которые были смерджены мердж коммитом

Tags: git, git-commit

Как найти коммиты по мердж коммиту которые были смерджены с другого бранча?
На картинке ниже зеленая ветка эта master, у меня есть SHA коммита под номером 1 но нет названия ветки которую вливали а найти нужно коммиты 2, 3, 4

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Любая IDE, наверное, предоставляет виузальный интерфейс для гита где все видно и можно 'найти' ) или команды `git log --oneline` предоставит список комитов, `git log --graph` выведит их в графе.

Comment: @asanisimov ответ еще проще  2, 3, 4. На эту картинку буду смотреть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git log --oneline коммит1^..коммит1^2`, где `коммит1` - любой идентификатор коммита 1, например его SHA-1 или ветка, указывающая на него

Расшифровка

Две точки в команде `git log коммит1..коммит2` означает: все коммиты из ветки, оканчивающейся `коммит2`, не входящие в ветку `коммит1`

Крышка в `коммит1^` - предок коммита (для слияния - ветка в которую был `merge`). В примере это коммит 5.

Двойка после крышки в `коммит1^2` - второй предок, то есть ветка, которую мы вливали командой `merge`. Доступно только для коммита слияния. В примере это коммит 2

Информация взята отсюда https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B8 и проверена на практике.

**PS** в командной строке Windows крышка `^` является служебным символом, поэтому ее придется удвоить: `git log --oneline коммит1^^..коммит1^^2`

Comment: А я не знаю название ветки которую с которой мерджили, как быть?

Comment: А вам и не нужно знать, их вернет `…^` и `…^2`. Внимательно посмотрите первую строку ответа.

Comment: Да, действительно, цифра 2 немного конфюзит, спасибо, долго искал это

Comment: Можно использовать `комит1~1` и так далее. Должно работать в Windows и *nix безо всякого удвоения.

Comment: @0andriy ни git log --oneline df324234324~1 ни git log --oneline df324234324~df324234324 ни другие комбинации не работают.

Comment: Вторая некорректна, а первая должна работать, если указанный хеш существует и не является корневым.

Comment: @0andriy да, первая работает, но выдает кучу других коммитов (кажется все коммиты которые есть в ветке, а их там о 50 000) которые не относятся к второму паренту и к тому же среди них нет того коммита который выдает команда указанная в ответе

Comment: Так вы читали по ссылке? ~ и ^ для первого родителя эквивалентны. У вас `git log commitID^` тоже выдаст много.

Comment: @0andriy В итоге какая полная команда должна быть? `git log --oneline df324234324~1` выдает кучу коммитов, без нужного коммита, команда `git log --oneline e5d88c82b11^..e5d88c82b11^2` выдает родителей из другой ветки из которой была смерджена, которая в моем случае один только коммит.

Comment: Едиственное улучшение это только для первого коммита, можно вместо ^.. использовать ~ а для второго коммита все равно нужна крышка, и все равно нужно удвоение в windows, конечно если пользоваться cmd